# About "6j symbol": How to understand a vertor space tensor with an object in a tensor category?

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a semisimple (multi)tensor categroy over field $k$, with simple objects $\{V_i\}_{i\in I}$. We define
$$
H_{i, j}^{\ell}=\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}\left(V_{\ell}, V_{i} \otimes V_{j}\right)
$$
so that tensor products are decomposed as:
$$
V_{i} \otimes V_{j}\cong\bigoplus_{\ell} H_{i, j}^{\ell} \otimes V_{\ell}\ \ \ \ \ (*)
$$

My question is: how to understand $H_{i, j}^{\ell} \otimes V_{\ell}$? We know that $H_{i, j}^{\ell}$ is just a vector space, instead of an object in $\mathcal{C}$. So, rigorously we never define what is a tensor between a vector space and an object in $\mathcal{C}$. Although, if $\mathcal{C}=\operatorname{Rep}(G),\ \operatorname{Rep}(\mathfrak{g})$ or other concrete examples (whose objects have a vector space structure),  there is always a natrual way to understand it.

Also, even if we can justify this, what is the isomorphism map in formula ($*$)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $C$ is a $V$-enriched category where $V$ is a closed monoidal category (here $V$ is the closed monoidal category of possibly finite-dimensional vector spaces over $k$), $c \in C$ is an object, and $v \in V$ is an object, then the **tensor** or [**copower**](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/copower) $v \otimes c$, if it exists, is the object in $C$ satisfying the universal property

$$[v \otimes c, d]_C \cong [v, [c, d]_C]_V$$

where $[-, -]_C$ denotes the $V$-valued hom in $C$ and $[-, -]_V$ denotes the internal hom in $V$.

If $C$ is enriched over vector spaces over $k$ and furthermore has finite biproducts, then the tensor with any finite-dimensional vector space always exists, since we can write an $n$-dimensional vector space $v$ as a direct sum of $n$ copies of the unit $k$ and tensoring, being a left adjoint, preserves colimits (when it exists), so

$$v \otimes c \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n c.$$

The given decomposition existing is part of the definition of being a semisimple (multi)tensor category, as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you! Let $X$ be a simple object in $C$ (So $\operatorname{End}_C(X)\cong k$). If there is two objects $V_1, V_2$ in category $V$ and a isomorphism/morphism: $\phi: V1\otimes X\rightarrow V_2\otimes X$, can we fine a canonical isomorphism/morphism: $V_1\rightarrow V_2$?

Comment: Here is my thought: $V_i$ is determined by $Hom(V_i,-)$. If $C(X,-): C\rightarrow V$ is essentially surjective, then for any $v$ in $V$, $v\cong C(X,Y)$ for some Y. Thus $Hom(V_1,v)\cong Hom(V_1,C(X,Y))\cong C(V_1\otimes X, Y)\cong C(V_2\otimes X, Y)\cong Hom(V_2,v)$. But this isomorphism is not natrual in $v$.

Comment: @likeeatingoctous: yes, we have $[X, V_1 \otimes X] \cong V_1$, by writing $V_1$ as a direct sum of copies of $k$ as above.